# How can i view actual state of ssh port-forwarding rules?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

In ssh session i pressed <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> then i defined forwarding rule, then got `Forwarding port.` response, then added another one. how can i view these rules at once? (not by scrolling terminal up)

```
ssh> ? 
Commands:
      -L[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request local forward
      -R[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request remote forward
      -D[bind_address:]port                  Request dynamic forward
      -KL[bind_address:]port                 Cancel local forward
      -KR[bind_address:]port                 Cancel remote forward
      -KD[bind_address:]port                 Cancel dynamic forward
```

wanted command -... display current port forwarding rules

Comment: netstat/ss are your friends.

Comment: I have `netstat` on local machine, not on shared remote computer

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the prompt you indicate in your terminal example. What software package/ssh client are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will list the tunnels created by ssh and sshd:

`lsof -i -n | egrep 'ssh'`

`lsof -i -n | egrep 'sshd'`

The following will list all zones and port rules:

`firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`

Comment: Nice! lsof do the trick! `IPv6 107472      0t0  TCP [::1]:8888 (LISTEN)`